# How can I make a 'global JAR library' accessible by every project I make in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, libs

**I searched for the answer to this but came away only with solutions for how to add JAR libraries to individual projects rather than globally to all. Also please correct me on the terminology if I'm wrong regarding my concept of a global JAR.**

Hi I use Android Studio on Windows and would really appreciate if someone can please tell me how I can add the same jar library to **every** project without having to copy the jar files into the libs folder of every project created.

Is there a way to make something like a symlink to the jars or can I somehow make them as an extension to the SDK.

I'm a newbie to Java and Android development so appreciate your patience and any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Thought about creating a local maven repository?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm testing the jPCT 3D engine on a number of Android Studio projects. The engine is distributed as a number of JARs and thought there would be an easier way to include the libraries.

Comment: @Ascorbin I don't know how to do that so will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: The right "easy" answer is for jPCT to be distributing their library via a Maven repository. Ascorbin's suggestion would be the next-best answer; see also [this jPCT forum thread](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php?topic=3599.0). Please bear in mind that your "number of Android Studio projects" may not be forever in lockstep, and so they each need to be able to pull in the right version of jPCT that their code is depending upon. The simple way to do that is with Maven-style repositories.